# Rename the uploading Image

Tags: php, javascript

i am uploading the image into the server , need to place the _ in place of gap in the image. Like if the name of image is Stack Flow.jpg, i need to send it as Stack_Flow.jpg in the directory as well in the email. HOw could be possible with the following code. i have tried but no success.. I am sending the 4 files in one form, code as ---

```
$filea = $_FILES['FILE1']['name'];
        $fileb = $_FILES['FILE2']['name'];
        $filec = $_FILES['FILE3']['name'];
        $filed = $_FILES['FILE4']['name'];


$order_image_a='order_'.$orderId.'_'.$filea;
        if(!empty($filea)) move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE1']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_a");

        $order_image_b='order_'.$orderId.'_'.$fileb;
        if(!empty($fileb)) move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE2']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_b");

        $order_image_c='order_'.$orderId.'_'.$filec;
        if(!empty($filec)) move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE3']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_c");

        $order_image_d='order_'.$orderId.'_'.$filed;
        if(!empty($filed)) move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE4']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_d");
```

i am using below function, how could i apply it for all four files--

```
<script>
function convertSpecialChars($str) {
    $str = str_replace( " ", "_", $str );
    return $str;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
<?php
    function convertSpecialChars($str) {
        $str = str_replace( " ", "_", $str );
        return $str;
    }
?>
```

And then your code:

```
$filea = $_FILES['FILE1']['name'];
$fileb = $_FILES['FILE2']['name'];
$filec = $_FILES['FILE3']['name'];
$filed = $_FILES['FILE4']['name'];


$order_image_a='order_'.$orderId.'_'.convertSpecialChars($filea);
if(!empty($filea))
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE1']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_a");

$order_image_b='order_'.$orderId.'_'.convertSpecialChars($fileb);
if(!empty($fileb))
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE2']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_b");

$order_image_c='order_'.$orderId.'_'.convertSpecialChars($filec);
if(!empty($filec))
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE3']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_c");

$order_image_d='order_'.$orderId.'_'.convertSpecialChars($filed);
if(!empty($filed))
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE4']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_d");
```

Or if possible, you could do it in a loop (less duplicate code):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)
{
    $file = $_FILES['FILE' . $i]['name'];

    $order_image = 'order_' . $orderId . '_' . convertSpecialChars($file);

    if(!empty($file))
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE' . $i]['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image");
}
```

Comment: again its not removing the gap with the given code as well :(

Comment: should i have to make it `variable` `convertSpecialChars` ?

Answer (score 2):

here is a quick example in php:

```
<?php

$name = "Stack Flow.jpg";
echo preg_replace('/[\s\-]+/', '_', $name );
?>
```

returns `Stack_Flow.jpg`

http://codepad.org/MQoEZ2wv

Answer (score 1):

This is not a script but PHP..

```
<?
function convertSpecialChars($str) {
    $str = str_replace( " ", "_", $str );
    return $str;
?>
```

//do the same for all other images..

```
$filea = str_replace(' ', '_', $filea;
$order_image_a='order_'.$orderId.'_'.$filea;
if(!empty($filea)) move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE1']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_a");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code change `$order_image_a='order_'.$orderId.'_'.$filea;` and other similar lines to
`$order_image_a='order_'.$orderId.'_'.convertSpecialChars($filea);`

But will better if you will know how work your code.